# Valores nulos en hashtable - Java

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña app en Java, en la cual hago una conexion a una base de datos y obtengo un campo JSON, ese JSON lo transformo a objeto, y posteriormente los voy insertando a un hashtable, y finalmente retorno el hashtable...

El Asunto esta, en que en la base de datos tengo 4 rows, y en la App al momento de agregar a la tabla los datos del hashtable, solo toma 3... Si agrego otro dato a la base ded atos solo toma 4 de 5... y asi sucesivamente

Codigo: (DatabaseConnection.java)

```
    public static <T> Hashtable<Integer, T> GetList(String Table) throws Exception{

    T obj = null;
    Hashtable<Integer, T> objs = new Hashtable<Integer, T>();
    int id = 0;
    String data;
    Connection Connector = Connect();

    try{

        Statement Stats = Connector.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + Table;
        ResultSet result = Stats.executeQuery(sql);

        while(result.next()){
            id = result.getInt(1);
            data = result.getString(2);

            obj = SerializerClass.Deserialize(data);
            objs.put(id, obj);
            System.out.println(id);
        }

    }catch(SQLException sqlEx){
        throw new Exception("Exeption Ocurred. " + sqlEx.getMessage());
    }

    return objs;
}
```

Codigo #2 (PrincipalForm.java)

```
public void UpdateGUI(){
    Columns = new String[] {"Nombre", "Servicio", "Fecha", "Estado"};
    n = new DefaultTableModel(Columns, 0);
    SessionsTable.setModel(n);

    try{
        this.SesionesList = DataBaseConnection.GetList("sesiones");
        if (!SesionesList.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SesionesList.size(); i++) {
                if (SesionesList.get(i) != null) {
                    String Name = SesionesList.get(i).Name;
                    PaqueteCasual Service = SesionesList.get(i).Servicio;
                    String fecha = SesionesList.get(i).Fecha;
                    Estado State = SesionesList.get(i).State;

                    Object[] data = { Name, Service, fecha, State };

                    n.addRow(data);
                }else { System.out.println("Is null"); }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.print("Its Empty.");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.print("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(SesionesPrincipalForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Por lo que he notado, es que al llegar al 4to valor, devuelve un null. Como podran notar en el Codigo #2, tengo un IF que confirma si es null o no, y efectivamente.. con los 3 primeros valores los toma, pero el 4to es Nulo

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SesionesList.size(); i++) {
            if (SesionesList.get(i) != null) {
                String Name = SesionesList.get(i).Name;
```

Estás intentando recorrer un `Map` como si fuera un `List`. No funciona así.

En las listas, buscas por índice, y sabes que va por orden. Así que el primer elemento será 0, luego `1`, así hasta `size() - 1`.

En los mapas relacionas una clave con el elemento, y buscas por la clave. Si hay 10 elementos, no tienes porqué poder recuperarlos usando como claves los números de 0 a 9, sino las claves que se usaron.

Por ejemplo

```
Map mapa = new Hashtable();
mapa.put("Hola", "Mundo");
System.out.println(mapa.get("Hola")); // Imprime "Mundo"
System.out.println(mapa.get(0));  // Imprime null, porque no hay ningún elemento que tenga 0 como clave.
```

Si quieres iterar, dos opciones:

- Usa una lista o array, que para eso están.
- El método `keys()` devuelve un `Enumeration` con todas las claves definidas. Iteras sobre esas claves, y para cada una de esas claves haces el `get` correspondiente.

Comment: Estoy llamando de esa forma, ya que defino como la key del hashtable el ID que extraigo de la base de datos... He notado un error de logica. 
igualmente, ya estoy reescribiendo ese codigo y teniendo en cuenta lo que me dijiste. Ty!